# String assignment in C

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C. The string assignment in the following code works:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char str[] = "string";
  printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

But doesn't work in the following,even I give the index number to the `name[]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  struct student {
    char name[10];
    int  salary;
  };
  struct student a;
  a.name[10] = "Markson";
  a.salary = 100;
  printf("the name is %s\n",a.name);
  return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: char name[10] is equal to char* name but with different allocation.

Comment: When you declare an array like this, `char name[10];`, you get an array with ten elements, numbered 0 to 9 inclusive. So `a.name[10]` is outside the bounds of the array. It's not a good idea to try to assign it a value.

Comment: You need to learn about arrays before you learn about strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign to an array. Two solutions: either copy the string:

```
strcpy(a.name, "Markson");
```

or use a const char pointer instead of an array and then you can simply assign it:

```
struct {
    const char *name;
    /* etc. */
};

a.name = "Markson";
```

Or use a non-const char pointer if you wish to modify the contents of "name" later:

```
struct {
    char *name;
}

a.name = strdup("Markson");
```

(Don't forget to free the memory allocated by strdup() in this latter case!)

Comment: Shouldn't `name` be a `const char*` in the second case? :)

Comment: @KirilKirov fixed, and added one more possibility. :)

Comment: Looks better now :) +1 for your competitive answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this

```
a.name[10] = "Markson";
```

You need to [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) the string `"Markson"` to `a.name`.

`strcpy` declaration:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

So, you need

```
strcpy( a.name, "Markson" );
```

Answer (score 3):

`char str[] = "string";` is a declaration, in which you're allowed to give the string an initial value.

`name[10]` identifies a single char within the string, so you can assign a single char to it, but not a string.

There's no simple assignment for C-style strings outside of the declaration. You need to use `strcpy` for that.

Answer (score 0):

because in one case you assigning it in a declaration and in the other case you are not. If you want to do the equivalent write:

```
struct student a = {"Markson", 0};
```

Comment: Although an initializer resembles an assignment (and thus the OP's confusion), it isn't one.