# C Char by parameter

Tags: c, string, function, compiler-errors, char

If I use a list like this:

```
typedef struct list {
    char information[20];
    struct list *next;
}
```

And if I try to pass the information through parameter of a function, for example:

```
list *createlist(char inf[]) {
    list *l = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    l->information = inf;
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

It does not work, the error is

```
[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [20]'
```

If i declare information like `char *information` and in fuction `list *createlist(char *inf)`, in this way it works, but the string is limited to 7 characters. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864410/string-assignment-in-c  If someone can find a better duplicate please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assignable. You'll have to copy the characters manually. Fortunately, there is a function called `strcpy`(from `string.h`) that does this for you. So change

```
l->information=inf;
```

to

```
strcpy(l->information, inf);
```

---

*Sidenotes*:

- Check the return value of `malloc` to see if it was successful.
- Make sure that `inf` consist of a maximum of 19 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator) to prevent a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `information` is of type "array". In the code

```
l->information=inf;
```

is the issue, as you cannot *assign* arrays.

If you meant to *copy* the contents, you need to use `strcpy()` function, declared in `string.h` header.

That said,

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. Always check the return value of `malloc()` for success before using the returned pointer.
3. Add the proper typedef for `list`. You need to write it like

   ```
   typedef struct list {
       char information[20];
       struct list *next;
   }list;
   ```