# Why my bzero() cause a bus error with my char array?

Tags: c, bus-error

I try to understand why my simple code who use `bzero` or `memset` cause a `bus error` with `clang`or `gcc` I find no logical explication.

I try the simple example from this post : [Proper way to empty a C-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107826/proper-way-to-empty-a-c-string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str;
    printf("%lu\n",strlen(str));
    bzero(str,1); // ok
    str = "bonjour";
    bzero(str,strlen(str)); // bus error
    // memset(str, 0, strlen(str)); // bus error
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `str` is a pointer to a string literal, those can't be changed, use `char str[8]`, `strlen(str)` is also bad as `str` is uninitialized.

Comment: `char *str` is an uninistailized pointer. You're just doing operations on random memory. This is not good. Instead do `char str[8];` or so.

Comment: I picked two duplicates, one for each bug mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: `str = "bonjour";` shouldn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864462

Comment: So the usual order of study C would be: arrays, then pointers, then strings. Not the other way around.

Comment: @JHBonarius, it's a valid statement, it assigns the string literal to `str` pointer, it just doesn't work as the OP would expect. It should be `const` qualified precisely to avoid what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Lundin - unless you're taking CS50 :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl, that's one of those things that should be uninvented :)

Comment: @JHBonarius and @anastaciu thx I solve the problem with an strcpy() for the moment. The thing me in the wrong when I wrote `str = "bonjour ` when I use `printf`the terminal write `bonjour`So i thought my code is ok, but not :(  thx at all.

Comment: @anastaciu I was using a C++ compiler. that's probably why it wasn't working for me ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius, yes, in C++ non-const qualified string literals are forbidden, thankfully. Though gcc and clang only issue warnings because of the C99 extensions, sadly.

Comment: @SteveFriedl In that case it they teach you to become a lost cause, so it won't matter.